Asking questions completely in Chinese
Prior to site launch I asked this question during the sites definition:
Will the Chinese Language site allow for questions to be asked completely in Chinese?
Which over time received 20 upvotes.
Not that this make it a consensus.
How would everyone feel about someone asking a question here completely in Chinese?

You obviously can, such questions are ok in language-related sites. And it's not a bad thing, it can be a good thing for practicing reading for beginners like me. :)
But on the French SE for example, some people — including myself — make sure to post also an english version, both in question and answers.
This is not mandatory, of course, but it would be helpful so you don't exclude people who can't understand chinese yet. Let's say it's a good habit. :D

To add on, I would say that long explanations lend themselves to a mix of Chinese and English, where as there are questions for which a shorter answer complete in Chinese which is not only acceptable, but preferred.

I just tried to do so. My question was blocked for lacking "proper English grammar."

I'm not sure what happened here.  I asked wholly Chinese questions: 1 2 3 4.  If I were to guess, it might be blocked for having a very short title or body.  If this happens again, can you please submit a bug report here on meta?
